# Adding to a Hashset inside a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I'm trying to add an object to a Hashset within a Hashmap.

Here `gamesAndTeams` is a Hashmap, and it contains a Hashset.

I've looked over some tutorials over the web but what I'm trying isn't working.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
Match newmatch = new Match(dateOfGame, stad, guestTeam, hostTeam, hostGoals, guestGoals);
gamesAndTeams.put(key, gamesAndTeams.get(key).add(newmatch));
```

Comment: Which one is your `HashSet` and which one is your `HashMap` ?

Comment: You should add the observed and desired output as well.

Comment: The question has already been answered but for future people looking into this question: gamesAndTeams is a Hashmap, and it contains a Hashset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Assuming `gamesAndTeams` already has an entry for `key`, you just want

```
gamesAndTeams.get(key).add(newmatch);
```

...you don't need to `put` anything in the map unless it was previously not in the map at all.

Answer (score 2):

You must first check if the key is present in the `HashMap`. If not, you should create the value `HashSet` and put it in the `HashMap` :

```
if (gamesAndTeams.containsKey(key))
    gamesAndTeams.get(key).add(newmatch);
else {
    HashSet<Match> set = new HashSet<>();
    gamesAndTeams.put(key,set);
    set.add(newmatch);
}
```

or

```
HashSet<Match> set = gamesAndTeams.get(key);
if (set == null) {
    set = new HashSet<>();
    gamesAndTeams.put(key,set);
}
set.add(newmatch);
```

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks. I forgot to remove the `HashSet<Match>` when I copied it from the first snippet.